# Could not load file or assembly... An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format (System.BadImageFormatException)

Tags: c#, .net

I have two projects in visual studio: Project A and Project B.
Project A is a console application and Project B is a class library. 
Project B is added as a reference in Project A.
Everything works fine on this point if I do not inherit any class in the Project B class.
But, when i add some other reference in Project B, and inherit those reference classes in the project B, it gives me error:

> ````
> program with an incorrect format (System.BadImageFormatException)```
> ````

This is Project B class which inherits `Script`.

Here, if I did not inherit `Script` class, this code works fine. But, after inheriting, it give me error.

Also, this script class comes form another reference library. I added this script class reference in both the projects but still got error.

```
public class Lclass : Script
{

    public Lclass() 
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("bla bla");
        //Console.WriteLine("bla bla");
        //Console.WriteLine("bla bla");
    }

    public void addsubmenu()
    {
        var _num = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < _num; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}


// this is project A class 

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

           // Console.WriteLine("bla bla");

            Lclass l = new Lbclass();
            l.addsubmenu();   
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check, that both projects target the same platform, x86/x64

Comment: both are set to any cpu..

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue is that there is a package being used in "Lclass", called from "Script" on the flow, that was not included as dependency on your Console Application. You must find out what package it is and include (through Nugget) in your Console Application project.

After adding such package, I suggest a dotnet restore, clean and building your project before running it again.

Let me know if it worked. I had similar issue last week and solved this way.